# WSO2 EMM Enrolling a device

Tags: android, wso2, wso2-iot

After getting the EMM product working and beign able to login into /emm I am now trying to enroll a device to see how this solution works.

I scan the QR code, go to the provided url, download the apk and install. Then I add username and password (BOYD) and it sais Autehntication. It does nothing after this, just hangs there for a couple of minutes untul it exits and shows login again.

IS there any other settings that needs to be in place before this will work?

Comment: And - which version of EMM do you use? Did you rebuild the app or you are trying to use the original settings?

Comment: original settings

Answer (score 0):

First add the following ling to **/repository/conf/log4j.properties** file to enable the OAuth debug logs in WSO2 EMM.

log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2=DEBUG

Then try to enroll the device again and provide the following information to check this issue.

- Android agent debug logs
- wso2carbon.log file in /repository/logs directory

Thanks,